# MaybeUninit versus Union

Tags: rust, language-lawyer, union, maybeuninit

Does the compiler behave differently with `MaybeUninit` or with a union with the same structure? If yes, what additional things does it do with `MaybeUninit`?

Specifically, is it the same (except for the different methods) to use original `MaybeUninit`:

```
#[repr(transparent)]
pub union MaybeUninit<T> {
    uninit: (),
    value: ManuallyDrop<T>,
}
```

or to use:

```
#[repr(transparent)]
pub union AnotherUninit<T> {
    uninit: (),
    value: ManuallyDrop<T>,
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MaybeUninit` is not treated specifically by the compiler (it is a lang item, but because the compiler needs to refer to it, not because it is treated specifically).

However, [`#[repr(transparent)]`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/60405) on unions is unstable, and [as explained in `MaybeUninit`'s docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/union.MaybeUninit.html#layout):

> Over time, the exact guarantees of `#[repr(transparent)]` on unions may evolve, and `MaybeUninit` may or may not remain `#[repr(transparent)]`. That said, `MaybeUninit<T>` will always guarantee that it has the same size, alignment, and ABI as `T`; it’s just that the way `MaybeUninit` implements that guarantee may evolve.

Other than that, I don't think there is a difference between std's `MaybeUninit` and a homemade one.